# Protect divide by zero in excel Let spill function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that spills across the columns in the below data to calculate the gross profit percentage:

[image: Gross Profit]

The formula I have so far is:

```
=LET(duration, SEQUENCE(1,StudioProjectedOperatingMonths,
COLUMN(I:I)),RevenueAndCosts,INDEX($1:$11,{8;10;11},duration), LET(x, 
RevenueAndCosts,IF(INDEX(x,1)=0,0,SUM(((INDEX(x,1)-INDEX(x,2)-
INDEX(x,3))/INDEX(x,1))*100))))
```

It's suppose to be taking each entry in rows 8, 10 and 11 and applying the following formula:

((Total Revenue - Total Costs) / Total Revenue) x 100

Total Revenue is row 8 and Total Costs are rows 10 and 11

Total Revenue might be zero for the month, so I have tried to protect against it with the If statement but it doesn't like the solution. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by removing the SUM -

```
=LET(duration, SEQUENCE(1,StudioProjectedOperatingMonths,
 COLUMN(I:I)),RevenueAndCosts,INDEX($1:$11,{8;10;11},duration), LET(x,
RevenueAndCosts,IF(INDEX(x,1)=0,0,((INDEX(x,1)-INDEX(x,2)-
INDEX(x,3))/INDEX(x,1)*100))))
```

Comment: You may also mark your answer as accepted for proper documentation.

Comment: can't do that for 2 days